# Check for unique and non-unique values in array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

We would like to get the result with full information, like Unique = Value1, Value2. Duplicate= Value1 . We have an array which is mention below it a sample array.

```
$array1 = array('John Wilkins', 'Poul Warner', 'Rodger Smith', 'David Bentham', 'David Wilkins', 'Brian Smith', 'David Warner', 'John Wilkins', 'Poul Warner', 'David Wilkins', 'Brian Smith', 'David Warner', 'John Wilkins', 'Poul Warner', 'David Bentham', 'David Wilkins');
```

We'll use this function with Numeric values. We would like to print the result in this format.

```
John Wilkins | Duplicate
Poul Warner  | Duplicate
Rodger Smith  | Unique
```

and so on.

Comment: A quick question so your question is not missunderstood. But how can **Value1** be both unique and a duplicate at the same time in `Unique = Value1, Value2. Duplicate= Value1`? Do you want to check the first and last names sepparetly? Or did you just do a missprint?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is pretty much what [`array_count_values()`](http://docs.php.net/array_count_values) does:

```
<?php

$array1 = array('John Wilkins', 'Poul Warner', 'Rodger Smith', 'David Bentham', 'David Wilkins', 'Brian Smith', 'David Warner','John Wilkins', 'Poul Warner', 'David Wilkins', 'Brian Smith', 'David Warner','John Wilkins', 'Poul Warner', 'David Bentham', 'David Wilkins');

$counts = array_count_values($array1);
foreach ($counts as $name => $count) {
    print $name . ' | ' . ($count > 1 ? 'Duplicate' : 'Unique') . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
John Wilkins | Duplicate
Poul Warner | Duplicate
Rodger Smith | Unique
David Bentham | Duplicate
David Wilkins | Duplicate
Brian Smith | Duplicate
David Warner | Duplicate
```

([demo](http://www.ideone.com/udMSP))

Comment: I would be very thank to you if can please make a complete code for above structure...like every name we print duplicate or unique.

Comment: @Rodger I don't understand. You want to e.g. print `John Wilkins` several times (each times with "Duplicate" prepended)? In that case, see [this example](http://www.ideone.com/1stbs).

Answer (score 3):

```
$array = array('apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'banana', 'apple',
'pear', 'kiwi', 'kiwi', 'kiwi');

print_r(array_count_values($array));
will output

Array
(
   [apple] => 2
   [orange] => 1
   [pear] => 2
   etc...
)
```