# Loop through key value duplicates in sub array

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to iterate through a simple array of arrays, then if I find duplicates of `'id'` value in a sub arrays, group them and iterate through them.

This can be obvious for you but I can't find a simple way to do this.

Example:

```
$records = array(
    array(
        'id' => 2135,
        'start' => 'january',
        'end' => 'march',
        'color' => 'blue'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2135,
        'start' => 'march',
        'end' => 'april',
        'color' => 'red'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5342,
        'start' => 'january',
        'end' => 'july',
        'color' => 'black'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5623,
        'start' => 'march',
        'key' => 'august',
        'color' => 'green'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5342,
        'start' => 'april',
        'end' => 'june',
        'color' => 'purple'
    )
);
```

Result needed:

All entries of id 2135 must be set to color blue.
All entries of id 5342 must be set to color black.

Comment: What do you mean by `loop through them` ??

Comment: I really do not understand your question. Please describes it carefully before you wanna get helps

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I need to go through each array. Correct me if I'm wrong but the array_unique will skip the duplicates?

Comment: Your “sub-arrays” only contain one element each, so what would you want to “loop over” there? This question makes little sense in its current form, please explain _properly_ what the expected result is.

Comment: @misorude they contain one element just as an example. Maybe I should put my real data to give more context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check for unique and non-unique values in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622280/check-for-unique-and-non-unique-values-in-array)

Comment: @wdotis , please put the exact initial array (complete) if you want a real help

Comment: @mlwn I have updated the post to give you more context. Sorry again!

Answer (score -2):

Try this solution

```
    $records = array(
        array(
            'id' => 2135,
            'start' => 'january',
            'end' => 'march',
            'color' => 'blue'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 2135,
            'start' => 'march',
            'end' => 'april',
            'color' => 'red'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 5342,
            'start' => 'january',
            'end' => 'july',
            'color' => 'black'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 5623,
            'start' => 'march',
            'key' => 'august',
            'color' => 'green'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 5342,
            'start' => 'april',
            'end' => 'june',
            'color' => 'purple'
        )
    );
    $collection = collect($records);
    $grouped = $collection->groupBy('id')->map(function($entries, $key){
        $color = collect($entries)->first()['color'];
        $e = $entries->toArray();
        foreach ($e as $key => $value) {
            $e[$key]['color'] = $color;
        }
        return $e;
    })->values()->all();
    dd($grouped);
```

Outputs

```
    array:3 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▼
        0 => array:4 [▼
          "id" => 2135
          "start" => "january"
          "end" => "march"
          "color" => "blue"
        ]
        1 => array:4 [▼
          "id" => 2135
          "start" => "march"
          "end" => "april"
          "color" => "blue"
        ]
      ]
      1 => array:2 [▼
        0 => array:4 [▼
          "id" => 5342
          "start" => "january"
          "end" => "july"
          "color" => "black"
        ]
        1 => array:4 [▼
          "id" => 5342
          "start" => "april"
          "end" => "june"
          "color" => "black"
        ]
      ]
      2 => array:1 [▼
        0 => array:4 [▼
          "id" => 5623
          "start" => "march"
          "key" => "august"
          "color" => "green"
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

Hope this help

Comment: duplicates in terms of ? id ? even if they have different start/end ?
which color should be assigned ? the first color found in the collection ?

Comment: You should explain your code so OP understands the solution - not just remembers it